# regex for "mentions"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to come up with a regex that would find the ampersat in the beginning of words only. For example:

Here: `The @dog went to the park.`

But not here: `The d@og went to the park.`

Or here: `The@dog went to the park.`

Essentially, I just want to capture normal "mention" behavior, while omitting weird edge cases. I feel that this is common enough that there must be some well-established regex for this.

Edit:

I tried with this:

```
/(@\w+)/gi
```

But, it captures cases that I do not wish to obtain.

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: That's an at-sign, ampersand is `&`.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Yes, its also called an 'ampersat', also, its javascript

Comment: Do you mean ampersand, ampersat, ample sand, amber sand or m% ?

Comment: @nmac I never knew it was called an ampersat.  Thanks for the education!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
/\B@\w+/g
```

`\B` matches at a non-word boundary, thus, it requires a non-word (or start of string) to be right before `@`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL6cL8/1)

```js
var re = /\B@\w+/g; 
var str = 'The @dog went to the park.\nBut not here: The d@og went to the park.\nOr here: The@dog went to the park.';
var res = str.match(re);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Would this allow for special username characters? For example: `-`, `. `, `_` ?

Comment: @zomars No, you must be facing a different kind of mentions. Try `\B@\S+\b` or  `\B@\S+` or  just `@\S+`.

Answer (score 1):

The regex should look something like this:

```
^@[A-Za-z]+|.+ @[A-Za-z]+
```

This will look for either `@` at the beginning of the first word, or `@` at the beginning of a word that follows.

Comment: It isn't always at the beginning. Look at the first example, it's after `The `.

Comment: You said "Here, but not here, or here" which means the first example is the only one that should be true. Otherwise, please edit your question.

Comment: I'm not the OP. Your answer won't work with the first example.

Comment: Oh sorry. And I realize I misread the first example somehow. Fixing it now.